# Is there a way to only draw attributed text on screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm creating an app that loads a huge amount of text into a `UITextView` (thousands of lines). Each line is syntax highlighted, so I'm using NSAttributedString to color it. This works fine, but the more text I load, the more processing power, time, and memory it takes to create all the attributed text.

Is there a way to find which lines of text will be on screen and then I can calculate the attributed text for this portion? I believe it would be possible with CoreText but I'd rather use something less raw.

Comment: In what form is your original not yet attributed NSString receiving its content? URLRequests, local textfile, output of a calculating model? Another parser of some kind? NSManagedObject?

Comment: Because you are actually looking for an `Prefetching` algorithm and if implementing such design pattern you would interact with the original object that holds the entire text to be attributed later to safe CPU power to the part that is visible to the user.

Comment: @OlSen The unattributed text is the disassembly of the file I opened

Comment: I suggest reading about NSLayoutManager, NSTextStorage, NSTextContainer. They may offer what you search for.

Comment: I'll look into it thanks.

Comment: here a nice article written by [Max Seelemann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413559/max-seelemann) how it came to NSLayoutManager and co https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/getting-to-know-textkit/